# Please can someone explain this exception for me and why "A RenderFlex overflowed by 125 pixels on the bottom"

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, listview, singlechildscrollview

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          //height: 270.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 215, 184, 221),
          child: Column(
           
            children: [
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I added

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
```

But the problem is still there. I also tried Expanded but the exception is still there. Thank you so much

Comment: Your code working correctly

Comment: yes @RavindraS.Patil is correct. your code is working fine

Comment: your code is working fine. no error show

Comment: It was throwing "A RenderFlex overflowed by 125 pixels on the bottom" exception but i have solved it by just removing the container and everything related to it. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

try to warp your SingleChildScrollView widget inside Expanded widget and remove container height

```
Expanded(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 215, 184, 221),
        child: Column(
          children: [],
        ),
    ),
  ),
),
```